# How to position specific record(s) at top of list

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I am working with all currency types and rates in a query. Because they are the most popular, is it possible to have USD and EUR positioned at the top of a query list before displaying the rest of the currency codes in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your table is called tblRate having two columns, Rate and Curr.
Create a query that uses the Switch function to assign a ranking order to USD (ranking order 1), EUR (raking order 2).
Assign ranking order 3 to all other currencies using the Nz function.
In your query you order by rank, next by currency.

SQL view:

```
SELECT Rate, Curr
FROM tblRate
ORDER BY Nz(Switch(Curr = "USD",1, Curr = "EUR",2),3), Curr
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table providing the source data for the list, add a 'OrderNum' column to the table, then put 1 and 2 into USD and EUR, respectively.  Then, in everything else, put a larger number, such as 3.  If they all need to follow alphabetical order after that, make the sort command have two variables in the query that provides data to the list box or drop down.  If your table containing the currency codes is called 'tblCurrencyCode', and the field containing the codes is called 'CurrencyCode', your code would look something like this:

SELECT CurrencyCode 
FROM tblCurrencyCode 
ORDER BY OrderNum ASC, CurrencyCode ASC

Answer (score -1):

An alternate method would be:

Create a query for most used currencies from your currency table and then join the list with your currency list query.

Something like.

```
Select currency 
from QryMostUsedCurrencies
Union all
Select currency from CurrencyTable
where currency not in (select currency from QryMostUsedCurrencies)
```

In this way, you can keep a list of most used currencies in a separate query. Either by dynamically looking at past transactions or simple select query from Currency Table for those items you want to appear on top. 
This helps you to change your `most used` currencies in one place rather than having ranking sql in multiple places.